# How can I execute a PHP file using the Ant script with php output in console, while executing file

Tags: php, apache, ant, exec

My ant script

```
<target name="testRunPHP">
    <exec executable="${php}" failonerror="true" dir="${source}">
            <arg line="${local.deploydir}/application/controllers/sleepTest.php"/>
            <arg line="-output" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

My sleepTest.php

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
set_time_limit(0);
apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $randSlp=rand(1,3);
    echo "Sleeping for ".$randSlp." second. ";;
    sleep($randSlp);
    if(ob_get_level()>0)
       ob_end_flush(); 
}
ob_implicit_flush(1);
```

if run file In Browser than display output while executing file
but in ant script display output (in console) after execution completed.
I want to display echo in console while file in process...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exec outputs each line to stdout. The problem in your php script is thta you output this to one line. All you need to do is to add '\n' at the end of `echo "Sleeping for ".$randSlp." second. \n";`. I've tested this with those scripts:

build.xml

```
<project name="exectest" default="test">

    <dirname property="build.dir" file="${ant.file}" />

    <target name="test">

            <exec executable="cmd">
                <arg value="/c" />
                <arg value="C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe" />
                <arg value="${build.dir}\test.php" />
            </exec>

    </target>

</project>
```

test.php

```
<?php

header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
set_time_limit(0);
apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $randSlp=rand(1,3);
    echo "Sleeping for ".$randSlp." second. \n";
    sleep($randSlp);
    if(ob_get_level()>0)
       ob_end_flush(); 
}
ob_implicit_flush(1);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. @Patryk Roszczyniała. run successfully. can you please help me to run `C:\xampp\htdocs\MyCodeIgniterApp\index.php my_controller/index`
its run successful in command prompt but in ant display error `[exec] Could not open input file: C:\xampp\htdocs\MyCodeIgniterApp\index.php my_controller/index` `[exec] Result: 1`

Comment: This is not a file `C:\xampp\htdocs\MyCodeIgniterApp\index.php my_controller/index`. What is this `my_controller/index`? Is it a parameter for php site? The best will be to edit question and paste ant script which you want to run. BTW. if answer is correct, you should check it as correct/helpful.

Comment: thanks for helping me. my_controller is codeigniter controller php file. and index is action of that controller. passing controller and is't action in argument and its working with cmd but not work in ant script

Comment: I understand now. This is command line parameter. Just add two args to run this propertly `<arg value="C:\xampp\htdocs\MyCodeIgniterApp\index.php">` and the second `<arg value="my_controller/index">`